# orderBy not sorting items in the following ngRepeat table

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is the table:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="col-md-1">Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr reportrowgroup="" ng-repeat="report in reporttree track by $index | orderBy:sortBy" report="report" rowindex="index" class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope">
      <td><a href="#">Marcos Dima</a></td>

(etc...)
```

This is the dropdown orderBy:

```
<select class="pull-right" ng-model="sortBy">
  <option value="createdAt">Sort by: <strong>Date</strong></option>
  <option value="adminRealname">Sort by: <strong>Username</strong></option>
</select>
```

Content in `reporttree` (sample):

```
[
  {
    "createdAt": "2015-08-12T13:06:54.901Z",
    "adminRealname": "Marcos Dima",
  },
  {
    "createdAt": "2015-12-12T13:06:54.901Z",
    "adminRealname": "Another name",
  },

(etc...)
```

But when I select `adminRealname` or `createdAt` from the dropdown nothing happens. Am I doing something wrong?

**EDIT:**

The table is a directive and it's in a separate table. Maybe that's the problem?

```
            '  </tr>'+
            '</thead>'+
            '    <tbody>'+
            '     <!-- <tr ng-repeat="report in reporttree track by $index"> -->'+
            '      <tr reportrowgroup ng-repeat="report in reporttree | orderBy:sortBy" report="report" rowindex="index"></tr>'+
            '    </tbody>'+
            '<!-- </div> -->'+
          '</table>'
```

Comment: try orderBy : 'sortBy'

Comment: Do your dropdown and table belong to the same controller? So that both reference the sam entity sortBy.

Comment: it works fine for me as long as your <td>'s are {{adminRealname}} format

Comment: @Jax my td's are: `<td><a href="#">{{report.adminRealname}}</a></td>`. And the table is a directive.

Comment: Please post your table directive code.

Comment: @alexchenco please see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `track by` must always be the last expression

You can read up on it [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#tracking-and-duplicates)

Please see working [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/198apu3d/)

```
var myApp = angular.module('application',[]);

myApp.controller('TestController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.data = [{
        createdAt: "2015-08-15T13:06:54.901Z",
        adminRealname: "Marcos Dima"      
        },{
        createdAt: "2015-12-15T13:06:54.901Z",
        adminRealname: "Another name"     
    }];
});
```

And the HTML

```
<div ng-controller="TestController as vm">  
        <select class="pull-right" ng-model="sortBy">
            <option value="createdAt">Sort by: <strong>Date</strong></option>
            <option value="adminRealname">Sort by: <strong>Username</strong></option>
        </select>
        <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="col-md-1">Name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="dataItem in data | orderBy:sortBy track by $index" report="report">
               <td><a href="#">{{dataItem.adminRealname}}</a></td>
            </tr>
       </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```